# Adjusting the Keyboard in Xcode without using UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to move the keyboard with respect to the textfield, which is hidden by the keyboard. I just want to adjust it for the textfield which is above the bottom button on my screen without using any scroll view. I have attached a screenshot of the textfield that I want to adjust with the keyboard. I have trued many solutions online but didn't help me at all. Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this library? https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: @ArikSegal No not yet! could you please let me know how shall I use it?

Comment: just integrate IQKeyboardManager library in your project. You just love it. You just need to write a single line to enable it for textfields/textviews rest taken care by library itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I will try it right away!

Comment: Also, you can use static table view inside `UITableViewController` if you are working with a storyboard.

Comment: @ArikSegal Thank you so much for the help! Really means a lot!

Comment: @Mahendra Thank you so much for the help! Really means a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the **IQKeyboardManager** library. No need to write code.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
        var window: UIWindow?
    
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
          IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    
          return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have uploaded the package into the swift package dependency. Could you please let me know what shall I do after that to use that library? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you get through the Read me the document of the Library?

Comment: Yes! I have followed the foliowing procedure:-                                               To install IQKeyboardManager package via Xcode

 * Go to File -> Swift Packages -> Add Package Dependency...
 * Then search for https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager.git
 * And choose the version you want

Comment: I have updated the answer, please use the library in your AppDelegate as explained.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help brother! It's amazing! 